# Import Theano on Anaconda of platform windows10

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I download the theano from github, and install it.
But when I try to import the theano in ipython, I meet this problem

### `In [1]: import theano`

`ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3397704bd624> in <module>()
----> 1 import theano`

`C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py in <module>()`
     40 from theano.version import version as **version**
     `41
---> 42 from theano.configdefaults import config
     43
     44 # This is the api version for ops that generate C code.  External ops`

`C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py in <module>()
     14
     15 import theano
---> 16 from theano.configparser import (AddConfigVar, BoolParam, ConfigParam, EnumStr,
     17                                  FloatParam, IntParam, StrParam,
     18                                  TheanoConfigParser, THEANO_FLAGS_DICT)`

`C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\configparser.py in <module>()
     13
     14 import theano
---> 15 from theano.compat import configparser as ConfigParser
     16 from six import string_types
     17`

`C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compat\__init__.py in <module>()
      4 # Python 3.x compatibility
      5 from six import PY3, b, BytesIO, next
----> 6 from six.moves import configparser
      7 from six.moves import reload_module as reload
      8 import collections`

`C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in __get__(self, obj, tp)
     90
     91     def __get__(self, obj, tp):
---> 92         result = self._resolve()
     93         setattr(obj, self.name, result)  # Invokes __set__.
     94         try:`

`C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in _resolve(self)
    113
    114     def _resolve(self):
--> 115         return _import_module(self.mod)
    116
    117     def __getattr__(self, attr):`

`C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in _import_module(name)
     80 def _import_module(name):
     81     """Import module, returning the module after the last dot."""
---> 82     __import__(name)
     83     return sys.modules[name]
     84`

`C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\theano\configparser.py in <module>()
     13
     14 import theano
---> 15 from theano.compat import configparser as ConfigParser
     16 from six import string_types
     17`
When I get into the files, I indeed can not find configparser.py in the directory, but the original file do not have it neither.

ImportError: cannot import name 'configparser'

Answer (score 0):

Just found the temperary solution , rename configparser.py to config_parser or any other name that are not confilct .

and change name of each module include it to config_parser .